# PHP: Using a namespaced class within several other namespaces at the same time

Tags: php, wordpress, autoload

I'm developing two WordPress plugins (exclusively for internal use) that both use the same set of PHP classes. The classes are identical except for their namespaces, and at the moment I've just copied the files from one plugin to the other, changed the namespace, and everything works fine.

Soon though I'm going to be developing more similar plugins that will also need these files, so I'd love to put them in a git submodule and just add them to any project that needs them. The problem is that multiple plugins needing them may be used on the same site, so if I move the classes to a submodule and give them their own namespace, then all of the plugins that use them would be trying to load the exact same classnames from the exact same namespace.

Is there a way to "reset" a class's namespace or re-name it somehow when it gets loaded, without editing the original file?

At the moment I have:

**SUBMODULE:**

```
namespace Submodule;
someClass {}
```

**PLUGIN A:**

```
namespace PluginA;
use \Submodule as PluginA_Submodule;

$classA = new PluginA_Submodule\someClass();
$classA->someMethod();
```

**PLUGIN B:**

```
namespace PluginB;
use \Submodule as PluginB_Submodule;

$classB = new PluginB_Submodule\someClass();
$classB->someMethod();
```

The site is loading, but only the class that loads first gets used -- i.e. Both plugins run `someMethod()` from plugin A.

Ideally what I want is for each project to use its own version of the files containing the exact same namespace and class names, and I suppose I should mention that each of the plugins are using Composer's autoloader to load them, so I had to add the `Submodule` namespace and the submodule directory to the autoloader array (in composer.json)  and `dump-autoload` to get this far. This is the part that may actually be the problem, but I'm not sure it would work if I wrote my own autoloader anyway...

Given that the classes are identical I normally wouldn't worry if the plugins all use the same one, but if I make a change to the submodule I might not immediately be able to update it in every plugin on every website, and obviously it'd be a problem if an older plugin is using a newer version of the class from a different plugin.

One thought is that I could potentially not give the submodule classes any namespace at all, if there's a way for them to inherit the current namespace or something when each plugin uses them. Not sure how the autoloading would work but I could just manually load those classes if needed.

Anyway, hope this makes sense and thanks for any help.

Comment: You might be interested in [Feature Project: Plugin Dependencies](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/02/24/feature-project-plugin-dependencies/). If this is just for internal projects though, you could just put the shared code in its own directory

Comment: A plugin dependency isn't quite what I need, as I need to pass variables and whatnot to the classes that I'd be using in the submodule, but thanks for the link -- it would be awesome if some core way to handle plugin dependencies existed!